# name 'self' is not defined when doing an unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing

**Edit**

So I did try again, with a new file called `test2.py` and it works. I packaged `repoman` , and `test.py` is in the `src` folder. I modified `test.py` after I created and installed my `repoman egg`. I think that's the problem. But thanks for the help. Do you guys think that's the exact reason?

---

```
import unittest
import requests
from repoman.core import ultraman, supported
from repoman.ext import writefile,locate_repo

class TestWriteFile(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.username = 'dummy'
        self.password = 'dummy'
        self.remote   = 'http://192.168.1.138:6666/scm/hg/NCL'

    def test_scm_permission(self):
        """
        Test SCM login.
        """
        r = requests.get("http://192.168.1.138:6666/scm/", auth=(self.username, self.password))
        self.assertTrue(r.ok)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Running `python test.py` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    class TestWriteFile(unittest.TestCase):
  File "test.py", line 19, in TestWriteFile
    self.assertTrue(r.ok)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I don't think I need to overwrite `__init__` function, do I? What's causing this? Why is `self` not defined? I already declared my superclass `unittest.TestCase`

Thanks.

I basically learned it from the official sample: [Unittest - Basic Example](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html)

Comment: That seems hard to believe. Are you 100% sure this is your exact code?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes. It is the exact code. So I did try again, with a new file called `test2.py` and it works. I packaged `repoman` , and `test.py` is in the src file. I modified `test.py` after I created and installed my `repoman` egg. I think that's the problem. But thanks for the help. Do you guys think that's a problem? If that's actually the problem, I'd edit my title.

Comment: No, I don't believe that's your actual code. If `self.assertTrue(r.ok)` fails then the line before will too. Therefore `self.assertTrue(r.ok)` won't execute.

Comment: @CppLearner.  I don't think it has anything to do with the egg.

Comment: I am very positive that that was my code. I checked my spelling many times before I came here (I've done that before...so yeah...). One possible reason I thought of was modifying test.py after installing the egg package is bad.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Yeah. It's possible not the cause. That's why I don't get. I am 108% sure it is the same exact code..

Comment: @CppLearner: Can't be. This question has no sense any longer, unless you can reproduce the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that what you showed is the actual code that get executed.

I and others belive that, for a couple of reasons:

- If `self.assertTrue(r.ok)` fails then the line before will too. Therefore `self.assertTrue(r.ok)` won't execute. *(as [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541397/name-self-is-not-defined-when-doing-an-unittest#comment12090465_9541397) said)*
- And because your code looks fine.

I'd say that you probably made a typo of this kind:

```
def test_scm_permission(self):
                         ^
                         |
         and wrote something here that's not self
```

In some file that get executed instead of the one you're showing.

Take a look at this example:

```
# test.py
class MyClass:

    def func(sel):    # typo error here
        self.name = 10


obj = MyClass()
obj.func()
```

And when I tried to run:

```
$ python3 test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    obj.func()
  File "test.py", line 4, in func
    self.name = 10
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

Having a traceback similar to yours.

**Note:** Also if I'm not counting wrong `self.assertTrue(r.ok)` is on line 18, instead of line 19 (which is the number showed in your traceback).

Comment: I think you're more or less right, but if the typo was there, it would have failed on the line above when it tried to find `self.username`.

Comment: @Rik Poggi  Okay. I will say "no it is not the exact code" because there a comment before the `self.assertTrue(r.ok)` But it was properly commented out. Removing it doesn't make it go away. So instead ofsaying it is not, I say it is the same exact code.

Comment: @CppLearner: So when testing this same code, you get an error right? Can you create an actual, minimal example that shows the issue?

Comment: @ThomasK: I agree with you. I don't think the error is coming from that file, but from a typo like that one somewhere.

Comment: @CppLearner: Try to put two or three `print` inside that file, and see all of them get executed or none will, etc... Maybe you have another `test.py` somewhere that get executed instead of the one you're showing.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure where the problem is coming from -- whether it's a copying error or the wrong test.py is being executed [update: or some mixed tabs-and-spaces issue, I can never figure out when those get flagged and when they don't] -- but the root cause is almost certainly an indentation error.

Note that the error message is

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

and not

```
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

which @Rik Poggi got.  This is exactly what happens if you move the `self.assertTrue` one level in/up:

```
~/coding$ cat test_good_indentation.py
import unittest

class TestWriteFile(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        """
        Doc goes here.
        """
        self.assertTrue(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

~/coding$ python test_good_indentation.py 
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

versus

```
~/coding$ cat test_bad_indentation.py
import unittest

class TestWriteFile(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        """
        Doc goes here.
        """
    self.assertTrue(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

~/coding$ python test_bad_indentation.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_bad_indentation.py", line 3, in <module>
    class TestWriteFile(unittest.TestCase):
  File "test_bad_indentation.py", line 8, in TestWriteFile
    self.assertTrue(1)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a rewording of David Heffernan's comment.

The code you posted cannot be the cause of that traceback.

Consider these two lines from your code:

```
r = requests.get("http://192.168.1.138:6666/scm/", auth=(self.username, self.password))
self.assertTrue(r.ok)
```

The traceback says the error (`NameError: name 'self' is not defined`)
 occurs on the second line (`self.assertTrue(r.ok)`).  However, this cannot have been the case because the first line refers to `self`.  If `self` were not defined, we would not get past the first line.

Therefore, the code you posted is not the code you ran.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but thought I'd add my two cents as it was not mentioned here. I agree with others that there is some type of spelling error in the original code. Look at this code carefully:

```
import unittest
import requests

class TestWriteFile(unittest.TestCase):
    def setup(self):
        self.username = 'dummy'

    def test_scm_permission(self):
        r = requests.get("http://192.168.1.138:6666/scm/", auth=(self.username, self.password))
        self.assertTrue(r.ok)
```

The code appears okay at first glance (and lint tools will not complain); however, I wrote **setup**, instead of **setUp** (note the capital **U**). This causes self.username not to be defined in the test_scm_permission context, because python did not automatically call my mispelled function name. This is something else to check if you're running into this type of error, but are certain you've defined the class members correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but not with self. It was a regular variable, defined the line before the error occured.

It was apparently due to ... mixin tabs and spaces.

I replaced all tabs by 4 spaces, and the problem disappeared.

For some unspecified reason, instead of the traditional indentation error, I had this one.